# Is it possible to make function of ubertooth using android smartphone?

Tags: android, wifi, rssi, dongle

I'm working on a project using Ubertooth. We will use Ubertooth to label using the visualized wave forms of the RSSIs received and determine what the signal is (WIFI, BLUETOOTH, ZIGBEE, ETC) using deep learning.

Currently I've been experimenting with a Linux Ubuntu environment using Ubertooth and some simple examples.

My question is whether Ubertooth can be implemented on an Android smartphone (comparably of the latest models).
Ubertooth knows it's a kind of dongle that scans the 2.4 GHz frequency band and gets the signal's value. But Android smartphones also scan and connect to wifi and Bluetooth signals.

So I thought that it would be possible to implement the function of Ubertooth using only Android smartphone. I want to know if it's possible to think and why. If there is anything I misunderstand, it would be appreciated.